# include comma separator in javascript for loop

Tags: javascript

I need to output the following:

12:00 AM - 12:00 AM,06:00 AM - 08:00AM,09:00 AM - 11:00 AM

However I am getting this:

12:00 AM - 12:00 AM
06:00 AM - 08:00 AM
09:00 AM - 11:00 AM

```js
var time = '00:00-00:00,06:00-08:00,09:00-11:00';
var slotTimeCount = time.split(',');
var cnts = slotTimeCount.length;
var mySeven = 0;
for (var sltCont = 0; sltCont < cnts; sltCont++) {
  //console.log(slotTimeCount);
  var time = slotTimeCount[sltCont];
  var splitTime = time.split('-');
  //console.log(splitTime);
  var splitTimeFrom = splitTime[0];
  var splitTimeTo = splitTime[1];
  var clinicFromTime = splitTimeFrom.split(':');
  var h_24 = clinicFromTime[0];
  var mins = clinicFromTime[1];
  var clinicToTime = splitTimeTo.split(':');
  var h1_24 = clinicToTime[0];
  var mins1 = clinicToTime[1];
  var h = h_24 % 12;
  if (h === 0) {
    h = 12;
  }
  var h1 = h1_24 % 12;
  if (h1 === 0) {
    h1 = 12;
  }
  var cnvrt = (h < 10 ? "0" + h : h) + ":" + mins +
    " " + (h_24 < 12 ? 'AM' : 'PM') + ' - ' +
    (h1 < 10 ? "0" + h1 : h1) + ":" + mins1 +
    " " + (h1_24 < 12 ? 'AM' : 'PM');
  console.log(cnvrt);
}
```

Comment: Please post formatted code, this is unreadable. We can't help you like this.

Comment: I've formatted your code a bit, but this post still needs work. What did you try to add the comma?

Comment: above my code i  need output like this -->12:00 AM - 12:00 AM,06:00 AM - 08:00AM,09:00 AM - 11:00 AM (include comma separator between the times), i dont know how to include comma separator in for loop, help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use [Array.prototype.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) method. I added only three lines to your code.

```js
var time = '00:00-00:00,06:00-08:00,09:00-11:00';
var slotTimeCount = time.split(',');
var cnts = slotTimeCount.length;
var mySeven = 0;

var str = [];

for (var sltCont = 0; sltCont < cnts; sltCont++) {
  var time = slotTimeCount[sltCont];
  var splitTime = time.split('-');
  var splitTimeFrom = splitTime[0];
  var splitTimeTo = splitTime[1];
  var clinicFromTime = splitTimeFrom.split(':');
  var h_24 = clinicFromTime[0];
  var mins = clinicFromTime[1];
  var clinicToTime = splitTimeTo.split(':');
  var h1_24 = clinicToTime[0];
  var mins1 = clinicToTime[1];
  var h = h_24 % 12;
  if (h === 0) {
    h = 12;
  }
  var h1 = h1_24 % 12;
  if (h1 === 0) {
    h1 = 12;
  }
  var cnvrt = (h < 10 ? "0" + h : h) + ":" + mins +
    " " + (h_24 < 12 ? 'AM' : 'PM') + ' - ' +
    (h1 < 10 ? "0" + h1 : h1) + ":" + mins1 +
    " " + (h1_24 < 12 ? 'AM' : 'PM');
  
  str.push(cnvrt);  // add to array
}

console.log(str.join(', '));   // join the array
```

Comment: @NelsonA You're welcome. Don't forget to vote up my answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

add a var final, and then replace the commas

```
final+=cnvrt.replace(/,/g,' ');
```

then show final at the end

```js
var time='00:00-00:00,06:00-08:00,09:00-11:00';
  var slotTimeCount=time.split(',');
  var cnts=slotTimeCount.length;
  var mySeven =0;
  var final="";
  for(var sltCont=0;  sltCont <cnts; sltCont++)
  {//console.log(slotTimeCount);
    var time=slotTimeCount[sltCont];
    var splitTime = time.split('-');
    //console.log(splitTime);
    var splitTimeFrom = splitTime[0];
    var splitTimeTo = splitTime[1];
    var clinicFromTime = splitTimeFrom.split(':');
    var h_24 = clinicFromTime[0];
    var mins = clinicFromTime[1];
    var clinicToTime = splitTimeTo.split(':');
    var h1_24 = clinicToTime[0];var mins1 = clinicToTime[1];
    var h = h_24 % 12;if (h === 0) h = 12;
    var h1 = h1_24 % 12;if (h1 === 0) h1 = 12;
    var cnvrt=(h < 10 ? "0" + h : h) + ":" + mins + " " + (h_24 < 12 ? 'AM' : 'PM') + ' - ' + (h1 < 10 ? "0" + h1 : h1) + ":" + mins1 + " " + (h1_24 < 12 ? 'AM' : 'PM');
    final+=cnvrt.replace(/,/g,' ')+' '; 
    }
    alert(final)
```